# NAT is not properly working on Linux 2.6.30

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, nat

I have an Internet Gateway Device with based Linux System (Linux 2.6.30).

I mad ean automatic script that open many http sessions from many LAN Stations to many Public IP address.
And I add capture on the wan interface and on the LAN interface And I found:

- Some time the NAT keep the private address of the packet when the packet is forwarded to the wan (rarely happened)
- Some time the NAT does not forward the TCP packet to the wan at all (rarely happened).

The above behaviour are rarely happened. If I launch the test 100 times it happens only 13 times.

Is it a known bug in the NAT of the Kernel? are there some patch to fix this issue?

Comment: Is it possible you've exceeded the number of connections set in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_conntrack_max` or `/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max`?

Comment: Could it be that some packets not properly NATed are from certain TCP connections whose handshake hasn't been successfully completed? Can you dump the packets?